# Jenkins Ant Build

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-numbers

I configured the Jenkins for the automation of ANT build for my project.
I installed the Build Name Setter plugin and got the desired name for every build as below using the ${BUILD_NUMBER} parameter

[image: Build Name Setter Plugin]

I would like get this build name in the jenkins server to be displayed in my application.
I have the script which picks the ${BUILD_NUMBER}.

I had to manually configure the release number in the script as shown.

[image: ANT Build script to pick the BUILD_NUMBER variable]

Can any one suggest me with a solution? It would be a great help.

Comment: Have you consider storing this value in the manifest ?

Comment: See; http://jreleaseinfo.sourceforge.net/ant_e.html

Comment: Did you try ```ant -D${BUILD_NUMBER}```?